# Generating a Coordinate System Which Contains 2 Vectors

Tags: python, math, vector, linear-algebra

I have 2 vectors in 3D space (world space). I need to find a relative coordinate system which places the two vectors on the same plane.

My thought was to first take the cross product of the two vectors to get a Z axis relative to both vectors. Then to make the new X axis, take the cross product of the new Z axis and one of the original vectors. Then to get the new Y axis, just take the cross product of the new Z and new X. But I do not think this achieves what I want. I have feeling that the x and y axis are not shared between the two vectors.

Here is the code I am using:

```
normA = TriangleA.forward.normalize();
normB = TriangleB.forward.normalize();

zaxis = normA.cross(normB);
xaxis = zaxis.cross(normA);
yaxis = xaxis.cross(zaxis);

zaxis = zaxis.normalize();
xaxis = xaxis.normalize();
yaxis = yaxis.normalize();

originx = str(TriangleB.verts[0][0]) + "mm";
originy = str(TriangleB.verts[0][1]) + "mm";
originz = str(TriangleB.verts[0][2]) + "mm";
```

**UPDATE**
To give a little information as to why I am trying to do this:
Eventually, I want to rotate one vector onto the other with a single rotation. In order to do this, I get the axis of rotation by taking the cross product of the two vectors. However, I need to generate a relative coordinate system from the axis of rotation and the other other vectors.

Comment: In order to rotate, what do you need, matrix, quaternion, axis and angle, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion your approach is partially correct. Each two vectors linearly independent define a plane. Cross product of such vectors gives normal vector of that plane which is 'z' offset as you have said. Now IMO you should use one of these two vectors to define e.g. 'x' axis. if you got 'x' and 'z' axis you achieve 'y' axis by cross product of these two.

Of course depending on the vector choice and calculation order you can receive different turn of result vectors. Also, operating in main coordinate system through relative one requires additional computing to map the values.

I hope I didn't messed up anything.

PS. And as I read your code again it seems that it is what you are doing. Maybe you want to achieve something else.

What do you mean by:

> I have feeling that the x and y axis are not shared between the two vectors.

Comment: When I say the x and y are not shared, I mean the new xy plane I create does not contain both vectors.

Comment: Referring to your "UPDATE" you want to achieve rotation of vector e.g. normA around new 'z' axis? If so, I think you should try 3D matrix transformations as a suitable approach.

Comment: I would use a rotation matrix, but the API that I am using only allows for rotations around x, y, and z.

Comment: Realized I was changing back to world before actually doing my rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct but you can save one cross product as yaxis is the same as normA.

The xy plane should contain both normA and normB